# module 'psutil' has no attribute 'cpu_percent'

Tags: python-3.5, psutil

Hello guys am new to python and i just started learning System tools in Python 3.5. I want to get my cpu usage for every 5 seconds interval, so i use `psutil`. But i am having an error. My code is below->

```
import psutil

cpu = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=5, percpu=True)

print(cpu)
```

and when i run this code am having following error->

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ayush/Documents/psutil.py", line 1, in <module>
    import psutil
  File "/home/ayush/Documents/psutil.py", line 3, in <module>
    cpu = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=5, percpu=True)
AttributeError: module 'psutil' has no attribute 'cpu_percent'
```

Why am getting this error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rename your file from `psutil.py` to something else.

Python now tries to import `cpu_percent` from *your* `psutil` as it has the same name as the module that you're trying to import.

After that things should work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

This should actually work:

```
import psutil 

print(psutil.cpu_percent(0.1))
```

Also make sure that you change your file name to something other than *psutil.py*.